# Django - Bootstrap table inline editing

Tags: django, contenteditable

I have a data table with all functionalities like sort and search. I want to add a col in the table that could be editable. I want to save the comments of the viewer.

I have the column in my model.py. but I do not know how to save it and keep it editable.

```
 <tbody>
        
      <tr>
        {% for a in data %}
        
        <td><a id="idclicked" href="datadescription/{{a.id}}/" title="click to see Metadata"  style="color: rgb(30, 61, 199); font-weight:bold;"><u>{{ a.id }}</u></td></a>
            <td>{{ a.Date }}</td>
            <td>{{ a.Name }}</td>
            <td>{{ a.Affliations}} </td>
            <td>{{ a.Methods}}</td>
            <td>{{ a.Instruments}}</td>
            <td>{{ a.device}}</td>
           
            
         <td>{{ a.comments }}</td>
         <td contenteditable="true">{{ a.editablecomments }}</td>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try making a 'save' button and post your data to your view using Ajax like so:

**Template**

```
<td contenteditable="true" class="edit" name="content" id="{{a.id}}">{{ a.editablecomments }}</td>
...
<button>Save</button>
...
<script>
    const itemsToBeSubmitted = []; // store edited items here 

    $(".edit").focusout(function(){
        let id = this.id;
        let value = $(this).text();

        itemsToBeSubmitted.push({
            value: value,
            id: id
        });
    });

    // Now you have an array all edited elements
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/someURLfunction',
            type: 'post',
            data: itemsToBeSubmitted,  // edited items
            success: (response) => {
                console.log('Saved successfully');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Views**

```
def someURLfunction(request, id):
    text = request.POST['itemsToBeSubmitted']
    something = SomeModel.objects.get(id=id)
    something.comment = text
    something.save()

    return redirect('index')
```

**Url**

Something like:

```
path('someURLfunction/<int:id>', views.someURLfunction, name='someURLfunction')
```

Helpful links:

[Ajax call to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835268/ajax-call-to-django-function)

[Save editable table text](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/editable-table-but-save-all-values) (although this is for laravel / php, the principle is almost the same)

Comment: Thank you for your help @Tim-Bolhoeve. I'm getting this error: Not Found: /model/someURLFunction. Not sure what i'm missing

Comment: Change "someURLFunction' to your model name

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance of Ajax. Could you tell me what i should add in the url             
        `$.ajax({
            url: '/someURLfunction'  `

Comment: You should add the url pointing towards your `urls.py`, wherein lies your views function.
It would work the same way as any other button or link redirected like: {% url 'something'%}, but instead, this time, you do it in ajax.

Comment: Example: if your `urls.py` contains something like: `path('savecomments/', views.savecomments, name='savecomments'),`, then your ajax would contain: `$.ajax({             url: '/savecomments'`, which then calls the `views` function `savecomments`, where you can do whatever logic you want.

Comment: i did that initially 
    
    `urls.py: path('editablecomments/<int:id>', views.editablecomments, name='editablecomments') `  
    
    views.py: 
    `def editablecomments(request, id):
text = request.POST['itemsToBeSubmitted']
something = rMetadataform.objects.get(id=id)
something.save()

    return redirect('index')`

        script:
     `document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: '/editablecomments',
          type: 'post',
          data: itemsToBeSubmitted,  // edited items
          
          }
      });`

Comment: still getiing the Not Found: /editablecomments error

Comment: This is because you call the url `editablecomments`, which does not exist because it is `editablecomment/id`, wherein the id is presumably an integer, to fix this you will have to give the paramter 'id' to your ajax url. Look at the first function in my answer that gives an id to the `itemsToBeSubmitted` function, in which you can assign that to the given url. It should look something like: `url: '/editablecomments/' +id,`.
Of course, this is just an example and will probably not work straight out of the box for you.

Comment: Here may be an answer that will help with getting the id in a url: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697028/how-to-put-id-value-in-ajax-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52697028/how-to-put-id-value-in-ajax-url)